# How should I assemble a text file (which holds the program) in to machine code file using command prompt?

Tags: assembly, system, command-prompt, cpu-architecture, machine-code

The program below works. However I need to turn it into machine code file, to do this I tried to use the command "jasm -a polled-io.txt". However this is not recognized. I believe it might be due to this command not being up to date (or I missed something). I'd appreciate some straight forward steps in order to do this. Thanks in advance.

Assembly code -> Assembler -> Machine Code

The text file is called "polled-io.txt".

This program reads 10 characters from the keyboard and then prints them all out once they've been entered.
Here is what inside:

```
            OSR      EQU   $E3       * Output Status Register (OSR)
            ODR      EQU   $E2       * Output Data Register   (ODR)
            ISR      EQU   $E1       * Input Status Register  (ISR)
            IDR      EQU   $E0       * Input Data Register    (IDR)

            ORG   0
            MOVE  #$00,B    * count is storage for our
            MOVE  B,count   *   counter value

   loop     MOVE  ISR,A     * Get ISR
            CMP   #$00,A    * is a char available?
            BEQ   loop      * no - wait some more
            MOVE  IDR,A     * read the char

            MOVE  count,B   * the address to write the
            ADD   #data,B   * value to is count+data
            MOVE  A,(B)     * write the char in there

            MOVE  count,B   * add 1 to count 
            ADD   #$01,B    *
            CMP   #$0A,B    * and see if we have reached 10
            BEQ   gotchars  * and move to next section if we have
            MOVE  B,count   * otherwise write count back
            JMP   loop      * and get another char
   gotchars MOVE  #$00,B    * count is storage for our
            MOVE  B,count   *   counter value

   write    MOVE  OSR,A     * get OSR
            CMP   #$00,A    * OSR 1 can print, OSR 0 can't print
            BEQ   write     * not yet, wait some more

            MOVE  count,B   * the address to read the
            ADD   #data,B   * value from is count+data
            MOVE  (B),A     * get the char in there
            MOVE  A,ODR     * print the char

            MOVE  count,B   * add 1 to count 
            ADD   #$01,B    *
            CMP   #$0A,B    * and see if we have reached 10
            BEQ   done      * and move to end if we have
            MOVE  B,count   * otherwise write count back
            JMP   write     * and write another char
   done     HALT            * done

count    DS.W $01        * the counter
data     DS.W $0A        * storage for our 10 characters
```

Comment: Have you installed `jasm`? What OS are you on?

Comment: You know you can't *run* this on a normal desktop/laptop, right?  It'd have to be in an emulator for whatever ISA this is.

Comment: Hi I am on Windows 10 home.  I'm not sure if I have installed Jasm, though I have jasper.

Comment: Peter Cordes, I see what you said. I never knew that, was not told in the book. Could you clarify on the steps if you get the chance?